# Plot a chart with percentage as secondary Y axis using R

Tags: r, charts, plotly

I want to plot a dual axis chart and I want the secondary Y axis (vcr) to be shown in percentage format. I tried multiplying the column by 100 and putting a % as ticksuffix to it but because the range of the data varies from 20% to 70% the Y axis labels are not shown clearly I get an output like shown in the attached image:

[image]

```
ay <- list(
      tickfont = list(color = "black"),
      overlaying = "y",
        showtickprefix = "all",
      ticksuffix = "%",
      #range = c(20,70),
      tickfix = "%",
      dtick = 0.5,
      side = "right"
      )
a <- list(
      title = ""
      )
b <- list(
      title = "" 
      )
m = list(
      l = 50,
      r = 50,
      b = 25,
      t = 0,
      pad = 4
      )

p <- plot_ly(data = ctv_graph, x = impression_date, y = impressions , name = "Impressions",type="bar",marker = list(color = toRGB("#00C0EF"))) %>%
      add_trace(x = impression_date, y = vcr, name = "VCR", yaxis = "y2") %>%config(displayModeBar=FALSE)%>%
      layout(xaxis=a, yaxis=b,  yaxis2 = ay, legend = list(x = 0, y = 1.15), margin = m)
})
```

Comment: Basic problem is too many ticks. `dtick` sets the difference between ticks. Use something like `dtick=10`

Comment: oh thanks a lot! it worked. I did not know about the dtick.